# why I get 405 on POST with gulp connect

Tags: php, server, gulp, localhost

Everything was working fine, I just start using gulp connect now on post I get 405, it's seem's to be server configuration issue, can some one help on this please

## My Gulp file code

```
        var config = {port: 9217,devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
            paths: {
                css:[
                    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*.css',
                    'src/**/*.css'],
            dist: 'dist/'
            }
        }
        gulp.task('connect', function() {
            connect.server({
                root: ['dist'],
                port: config.port,
                base: config.devBaseUrl,
                livereload: true,
                headers: {
                allow: 'GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS'
            }
            });
        });
```

## And JS file POST

```
$Scope.no_login = function(x, y) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "log.php",
        data: {
            user_name: x,
            password: y
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });
```

Comment: `405` means you are using wrong method (deprecated maybe?) http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Comment: It can't be wrong method, since this same setup work with when I use MAMP, XAMPP. I just try to migrate to gulp connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bit research I found that **gulp Connect** runs a server on top of NodeJS, which only execute JavaScript, not PHP. So I need to find gulp server solution with a PHP module and I use gulp-connect-php with browser-sync now work fine.